# CKEditor custom buttons state

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I'm trying to create custom toolbar separated from editor and it should contain all basic commands. Here is example of "bold" button.

```
<div class="tool bold" ng-click="editor.instance.execCommand('bold')" ng-class="{'active' : editor.instance.getCommand('bold').state == 1}"></div>
```

It works, but the state is not always correct. When I selecting bold text, the state changes, but when I simply move cursor using keyboard arrows, it remains the same.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Just a note, as I'm not sure what your goals are, but perhaps the existing [Shared Space](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sharedspace.html) plugin is something that you could use instead of coding a custom solution? It lets you detach the toolbar from the editing area and use one toolbar with multiple CKEditor instances.

Comment: @AnnaTomanek, Thanks for advice, maybe it will help me in the future. But for now, unfortunately, I need to build a custom toolbar.